# Why is the ILS_best_p not giving me the vector I want?

Tags: c++, heuristics

I would like to store the smallest value of compute_evaluation_function in current_best_eval, and the corresponding vector that gives that smallest value in ILS_best_p, I've succeeded with the current_best_eval, but can't seem to get it for the ILS_best_p even though they're under the same if statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

long int **read_matrix(ifstream &input, long int n);
double ran01(long int *idum);
long int *generate_random_vector(long int n);
unsigned long int compute_evaluation_function(long int n);
void first_2_opt_symmetric (long int n);
void swap(long int pos_1, long int pos_2, long int *);
void perturbation(long int pert_size);
long int *p;//the vector generated from generate_random_vector()
long int **d;//one of the matrices read from file
long int **f;//one of the matrices read from file
long int n;
long int actual_solution_value;
long int new_eval;
long int current_eval;

#define IA 16807
#define IM 2147483647
#define AM (1.0/IM)
#define IQ 127773
#define IR 2836

int main()
{
    string name;
    long int optimum;
    ifstream infile;
    long int initial_eval;
    long int *ILS_best_p;
    long int new_vs_current;
    new_vs_current = INT_MAX;
    long int current_best_eval;
    current_best_eval = INT_MAX;
    long int new_current_eval;
    long int best_eval;
    long int improvement;
    long int i;
    long int j;

    infile.open("nug12.dat");
    infile >> name;
    cout << "Name: " << name << "\n";

    infile >> n;
    cout << "Rows and Columns: " << n << "\n";

    infile >> optimum;
    cout << "Optimum solution: " << optimum << "\n";

    d=read_matrix(infile, n);
    f=read_matrix(infile, n);
    cout << endl;

    p=generate_random_vector(n); 
    compute_evaluation_function(n);
    cout << endl;
    first_2_opt_symmetric (n);
    cout << endl;   
    initial_eval = compute_evaluation_function(n);
    cout << endl << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) //ILS loop
    {
        if (new_eval < current_eval)
        {
            new_vs_current = new_eval;
            cout << "iteration 1st = " << i+1 << " " << endl;   
        }
        else if (current_eval < new_eval)
        {
            new_vs_current = current_eval;
            cout << "iteration 2nd = " << i+1 << " " << endl;           
        }
        cout << "iteration = " << i+1 << " " << endl;
        cout << " Vector before perturbation = ";
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << p[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << endl << "current best eval = " << current_best_eval << endl; 
        perturbation(3); 
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << endl << "current best eval = " << current_best_eval << endl; 

        cout << " Vector after perturbation = ";
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << p[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl << endl;    

        cout << endl << "current best eval = " << current_best_eval << endl; 

        first_2_opt_symmetric (n);

        new_current_eval = compute_evaluation_function(n);
        cout << endl << "current best eval = " << current_best_eval << endl; 

        cout << endl;

        cout << " Vector after local search = ";
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << p[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << endl << "current best eval = " << current_best_eval << endl; 

        cout << " Vector p = ";
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << p[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl << endl;  

        if (new_current_eval < current_best_eval)
        {
            new_eval = new_current_eval;
            cout << "iteration 3rd = " << i+1 << " " << endl;
        }
        else if (current_best_eval <= new_current_eval)
        {
            new_eval = current_best_eval;
            cout << "iteration 4th = " << i+1 << " " << endl;           
        }

        if (new_eval < new_vs_current)
        {
            current_best_eval = new_eval;
            cout << "iteration 5th = " << i+1 << " " << endl;
            ILS_best_p = p;         
        }
        else if (new_vs_current < new_eval)
        {
            current_best_eval = new_vs_current;
            cout << "iteration 6th = " << i+1 << " " << endl;   
            ILS_best_p = p;     
        }

        cout << endl << "current best eval = " << current_best_eval << endl; 
    }
    cout << endl << "current best eval = " << current_best_eval << endl;

    cout << "ILS best vector = ";
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << ILS_best_p[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}

long int **read_matrix(ifstream &input, long int n)
{

    /*    
    FUNCTION:       read instance matrices
    INPUT:          instance file name, instance size
    OUTPUT:         d-matrix and f-matrix
    (SIDE)EFFECTS:  none
    COMMENTS:       read the distance matrix and flow matrix
    */


    long int i, j;
    long int **matrix = new long int *[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new long int[n];
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if( !(input >> matrix[i][j]) )
            {
                cerr << "Error reading at " << i << j << endl;
            exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

double ran01(long int *idum)
{

    /*
    FUNCTION:      returns a pseudo-random number
    INPUT:         a pointer to the seed variable
    OUTPUT:        a pseudo-random number uniformly distributed in [0,1]
    (SIDE)EFFECTS: changes the value of seed
    */


    long k;
    double ans;

    k =(*idum)/IQ;
    *idum = IA * (*idum - k * IQ) - IR * k;
    if (*idum < 0 )
    {
        *idum += IM;
    }
    ans = AM * (*idum);
    return ans;
}

long int *generate_random_vector(long int n)
{

    /*    
    FUNCTION:      generates a random vector
    INPUT:         vector dimension
    OUTPUT:        returns pointer to vector, free memory when vector is not needed anymore
    (SIDE)EFFECTS: none
    */


    long int  i, j, help;
    long int  *v;
    srand(time(0));
    long int seed=rand();

    v = new long int[ n ];

    for ( i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
    {
        v[i] = i;
    }

    for ( i = 0 ; i < n-1 ; i++)
    {
        j = (long int) ( ran01( &seed ) * (n - i));
        assert( i + j < n );
        help = v[i];
        v[i] = v[i+j];
        v[i+j] = help;
    }
    return v;
}

unsigned long int compute_evaluation_function(long int n)
{

    /*
    FUNCTION:      compute evaluation function
    INPUT:         pointer to solution
    OUTPUT:        evaluation function
    (SIDE)EFFECTS: none
    COMMENTS:      none
    */

    long int i, j;
    unsigned long obj_f_value;

    obj_f_value = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            obj_f_value += d[i][j] * f[p[i]][p[j]];
        }
    }
    cout << obj_f_value;
    return obj_f_value;
}

void first_2_opt_symmetric (long int n)
{
    /*    
    FUNCTION:      first improvement 2-opt local search for symmetric instances
    INPUT:         pointer to some initial assignment
    OUTPUT:        none
    (SIDE)EFFECTS: initial assignment is locally optimized, dlb is used to increase the search speed, the dlb value is changed to false if item change it's location during perturbation
    COMMENT:       neighborhood is scanned in random order, use of register for faster computation
    */

    long int improvement = 1;
    long int improve_item = 0;
    long int u, v, i, j, k;
    long int tmp;
    long int *x;  

    improvement = 1;
    x = generate_random_vector(n);

    while (improvement)
    {
        improvement = 0;
        for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
        {
            u = x[i];
            improve_item = 0;
            for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ )
            {
                v = x[j];
                if (u == v)
                    continue;
                tmp = 0;
                for ( k = 0 ; k < n ; k++ )
                {
                    if ( (k != u) && (k != v) )
                    {
                        tmp += (d[u][k] - d[v][k]) * (f[p[v]][p[k]] - f[p[u]][p[k]]);
                    }    
                }
                if (tmp < 0)
                {
                    improvement = 1;
                    improve_item = 1;    
                    swap (u, v, p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    delete []x;
}

void swap(long int pos_1, long int pos_2, long int *p)
{

    /*
    FUNCTION:      swap position of two items in a vector
    INPUT:         position 1, position 2, pointer to vector
    OUTPUT:        none
    (SIDE)EFFECTS: none
    COMMENTS:      none
    */

    long int tmp;

    tmp = p[pos_1];
    p[pos_1] = p[pos_2];
    p[pos_2] = tmp;
}

void perturbation(long int pert_size)
{
    /*    
    FUNCTION:         apply random perturbation
    INPUT:            pointer to solution, perturbation scheme, perturbation strength, change in perturbation, end perturbation size
    OUTPUT:           none
    (SIDE)EFFECTS:    new solution formed from old solution
    COMMENTS:         none
    */

    long int hold_value[n];         //allocate memory for items to be chosen in move/*
    int chosen[pert_size];          //*allocate temporary memory to determine items to be moved */*
    long int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        hold_value[i] = p[i];               //initialize hold_value with the same value from local search/*
    }
    int j = n - 1;
    int rand_number;
    int rand_no;

    for(i = 1; i <= pert_size; i++)
    {
        rand_number = rand();
        rand_no = rand_number % j;              //choose random number from 1 to size - 1/
        chosen[i - 1] = rand_no + i;            //copy the value to chosen[i]
        j--;
    }   
    long int temp;

    for(i = 0; i < pert_size; i++)
    {
        temp = chosen[i];
        swap(i, temp, hold_value);              //swap chosen[i] and hold_value[i]; n first item in hold_value[i] is the index array that will be included in perturbation/
    }

    long int temp1;
    long int temp2;
    temp1 = p[hold_value[1]];//
    temp2 = p[hold_value[0]];

    for(i = 0; i < pert_size - 1; i++)
    {
        p[hold_value[i + 1]] = temp2;
        temp2 = temp1;
        temp1 = p[hold_value[i + 2]];
    }

    p[hold_value[0]] = temp2;

    actual_solution_value = compute_evaluation_function(n);
    new_eval = actual_solution_value;
    current_eval = new_eval;
}
```

This is the file I read from:

```
Nug12
12
578
0 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 5
1 0 1 2 2 1 2 3 3 2 3 4
2 1 0 1 3 2 1 2 4 3 2 3
3 2 1 0 4 3 2 1 5 4 3 2
1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 1 2 3 4
2 1 2 3 1 0 1 2 2 1 2 3
3 2 1 2 2 1 0 1 3 2 1 2
4 3 2 1 3 2 1 0 4 3 2 1
2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3
3 2 3 4 2 1 2 3 1 0 1 2
4 3 2 3 3 2 1 2 2 1 0 1
5 4 3 2 4 3 2 1 3 2 1 0

0 5 2 4 1 0 0 6 2 1 1 1
5 0 3 0 2 2 2 0 4 5 0 0
2 3 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 2 2 2
4 0 0 0 5 2 2 10 0 0 5 5
1 2 0 5 0 10 0 0 0 5 1 1
0 2 0 2 10 0 5 1 1 5 4 0
0 2 0 2 0 5 0 10 5 2 3 3
6 0 5 10 0 1 10 0 0 0 5 0
2 4 5 0 0 1 5 0 0 0 10 10
1 5 2 0 5 5 2 0 0 0 5 0
1 0 2 5 1 4 3 5 10 5 0 2
1 0 2 5 1 0 3 0 10 0 2 0
```

Comment: You seem to be confused with how pointers work. `ILS_best_p = p` only copies the address of the array, not the contents of it. You need to create another array and copy the data in it. Since you're using C++, it would be better to use a C++ `vector` instead of a C array. Assigning two C++ `vector` instances will copy the data. BTW, your use of *vector* is confusing since it is not a C++ `vector`, but a C array.

Comment: To get more attention to your question, try showing a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @pcarter wouldn't that mean `ILS_best_p` will have the address of `p` and when I print `ILS_best_p` the value of `p` will appear? So you mean I'll have to do something like `new arrayName[n] = *p`, only then `ILS_best_p = arrayName[n]`? Also I'm sorry but I don't understand regarding the C++ vector and C array, can you give an example from my coding?

Comment: @mike sorry about that, but I think it's hard for me to show a simpler reproducible example, since all the functions are related, the most I can do is to remove a few lines I used to see which 'if' statement the code enters.

Comment: The variable `p` holds the memory address of the array. `ILS_best_p = p` just copies this address. You need to copy the contents of this array into another array. This can be done using a `for` loop that copies each element of the array. (Other methods would use `std::copy` or `memcpy`). You should read up on how pointers work in C. There are lots of tutorials online. If you're using C++, you should also learn to use `std::vector`. Real C++ code should rarely if ever use raw array pointers as you are doing. Raw pointers are much more error prone as you are discovering.

Comment: Another fact to realize is that the value of `p` doesn't change in your code after you initialize it. `ILS_best_p = p` makes both variables aliases to the same array. It only copies the address from one variable to another. You can use `ILS_best_p` and `p` interchangeably from that point on. `p[0] = 1.0` will change the value that `ILS_best_p[0]` has since they point to the same memory address. Try putting `std::cout << p << " " << ILS_best_p << std::endl;` in your code to see that the same number (address) is displayed. Better yet learn to use a debugger and you can do as the program is run.

Comment: @pcarter Alright I understand the for loop. Sorry but I'm really lost in pointers, when you say the value of `p` doesn't change, do you mean the address or the value? If the value is the case, when I print `p` like how I print an array after the function call of `perturbation` and `first_2_opt` as you can see in my code, the outputs are different. However I think I understand what you mean, when I have `ILS_best_p = p`, `ILS_best_p` has the same address as `p`, and although the code doesn't enter the `if` statement, the value at the address is still updated, so I won't get the value I want.

Comment: Also, most part of the code was from my lecturer, the one I want to mention is the `generate_random_vector` function, so if I want vector `p` to be able to hold the value from the function, I have to have `p` as long int*, also worth mentioning is that my lecturer uses C, and I was asked to use C++, my lecturer suggested that I can either use pointers or vectors, but since both were out of my syllabus, so they're both strangers to me, so I chose to use pointers since my lecturer uses pointers in his code.

Comment: The value of `p` is an address. So your question doesn't really make sense. You will see this if you print it out. `p[i]` is the i-th element of the array that `p` points to. Think of memory as an array of numbered PO boxes. The array is then a sequence of adjacent PO boxes where you can store ints. `p` is the *number* of the first PO box of the array. It tells you where to *find* PO boxes. `p[0]` is the first PO box of the array, `p[1]` is the second one, etc. `ILS_best_p = p` just copies the PO box number. `x = p[0]` copies the contents of the first PO box of the array.

Comment: @pcarter now I understand. 
By the way, I added something like this but received error:
`long int *array = new long int [n];`
then in the 'if' statements, 
`for ( j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
     array[j] = p[j];
     ILS_best_p[j] = array[j];
}`
The error I received was segmentation fault, the debugger stopped after it enters the if statement with `iteration 5th`, did I do something wrong about the array?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing all the new code. But one thing that stands out is `array`. Why do you need this? You need to point `ILS_best_p` to a new array to store data into: `ILS_best_p = new long[n]` Then you just need `ILS_best_p[j] = p[j]` in your loop. If you weren't setting `ILS_best_p` to point to a new array, you would get a seg fault since it would have some random value (address) in it and your program would be accessing invalid memory.

Comment: @pcarter Oh that worked perfectly, guess I misunderstood your meaning when you say to save in another array. You are a great help! Thanks a lot!